# Error converting 1 input parameters for Function: Cannot convert input parameter 'token' to type 'System.Threading.CancellationToken'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated

I've implemented an Azure Function based on the Isolated model. The function processes message from a topic subscription on Azure Service Bus. The definition on the `Run` method looks similar to this:

```cs
[Function("MyFunction")]
public async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "subscription", Connection = "connectionString")]string mySbMsg,
    CancellationToken token)
```

The function is running and processing messages. But I see errors like this logged from time to time:

```cs
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionInputConverterException: Error converting 1 input parameters for Function 'MyFunction': Cannot convert input parameter 'token' to type 'System.Threading.CancellationToken' from type 'System.String'. Error:System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'p' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'p' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.ContinueDeserialize(ReadBufferState& bufferState, JsonReaderState& jsonReaderState, ReadStack& readStack)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.DeserializeAsync(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.DeserializeAsObjectAsync(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Converters.JsonPocoConverter.GetConversionResultFromDeserialization(Byte[] bytes, Type type) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Converters\JsonPocoConverter.cs:line 66
   at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Context.Features.DefaultFunctionInputBindingFeature.BindFunctionInputAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Context\Features\DefaultFunctionInputBindingFeature.cs:line 94
   at MyFunction.DirectFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\1\s\src\MyFunction\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators.FunctionExecutorGenerator\GeneratedFunctionExecutor.g.cs:line 32
   at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13
```

The error seems to happen in some generated source code:

```cs
/// <inheritdoc/>
public async ValueTask ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context)
{
    var inputBindingFeature = context.Features.Get<IFunctionInputBindingFeature>();
    // ⬇️ The error happens when calling BindFunctionInputAsync
    var inputBindingResult = await inputBindingFeature.BindFunctionInputAsync(context);
    var inputArguments = inputBindingResult.Values;
```

I don't understand why the generated code is trying to parse the `CancelationToken` as JSON. I already have the JSON sent over the service bus as the first parameter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can send a message to the Service Bus topic without errors. See the [output](https://i.imgur.com/qff8tVw.png).

Comment: I can too. As stated, this only happens sometimes. Most of the invocations process the service bus message just fine.

Comment: @ThimasArdal from where you got that source code? Can you share the complete code will check once where you are getting the error.

Comment: The source code is embedded in the log message that revealed this error. I'm getting help on the discussions page on the isolated functions repo now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While facing the same error I found this post and people saying updating fixed it.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2040

It did not solve it 100% for me as it works from VS and in the devops pipeline, but not when running from a script in my local machine.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. But I don't think this will fix it. I'm already on `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk` version `1.16.4` and the fix should have been in `1.16.1`.